# Time to burn our subscription to this [newsletter]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I encountered the tag [newsletter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/newsletter) today, and I don't see how it would be on topic on Stack Overflow. The tag has no wiki entry and its excerpt doesn't describe when it should be used, but what it is:

> A email [sic] or document containing a one [sic] or more news stories that will be distributed to a group of subscribers.

To answer the usual questions:

- **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**
  No, it's been used to talk about a newsletter distribution, a newsletter API, Plugin recommations (for Word Press), writing HTML forms, and various other completely different providers or tools that might be used to create, consume distribute a newsletter.
- **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**
  No. The document could be printed media and purely created from a word document (nothing to do with programming). If emailed, the question would be about how to write the part of that application that is doing mass mailing; what the content of that mass email is irrelevant. If it's about API consumption, then it should be about the language being used to consume that API. Tool recommendation is completely off-topic.
- **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**
  Nope, none. That the content is a newsletter is irrelevant to the programming question.
- **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**
  As in it's a Newsletter, yes, but as mentioned it could be about printed media or emailed content (which is quite different), or consumption of an API and tool recommendation which is *completely* different.

For questions that are [only tagged](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1794073/one-tag-one) with [newsletter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/newsletter), I would suggest that they are edited to have relevant tags added or voted off-topic; for other questions the tag doesn't add anything so could just be burned.

Comment: It would be interesting to hear the counter arguments for retaining the tag here, from the user who disagrees with the burnination. Could they post an answer, please?

Answer (score 36):

I wholeheartedly agree with this burnination request. The [newsletter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/newsletter) tag adds nothing of relevance to the Stack Overflow site, whatsoever. From a programming point-of-view, the fact that an email is (or contains) a "newsletter" (whatever one's idea of what that means) is not significantly different from an email that offers SEO or (perish the thought of a new tag) "male member enlargement" and similar spam.

Furthermore, as Thom A has hinted, this would be a relatively easy tag to burn: simple removal from many/most of the Qs that have it, or just replacing with a language/platform tag where it is the only current tag.

Comment: I've gone ahead and VTC'd a few of the [[tag:newsletter]] only questions, and added an on-topic tag on others (such as [[tag:html]]).

Comment: @ThomA Sure, go ahead and close vote those Qs that are clearly off-topic. However, no matter the issue, please stick to the formal process when it comes to tag removal as a whole. In this case, I think there will be a clear consensus...

Comment: I've not removed the tag from anything; there were only 6 that only had the tag and none others. A drop in the ocean compared.to the 800+ questions.